# Ios Swift 3 table view controller Constraints mess up after segueing back and forth in navigation controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, swift3

Im having an issue with my table view controller in swift 3. I have a very simple Cell configured as a prototype where an Image is on the left side of the cell, and a text label takes up 3/4 of the space after the image going towards the right side of the cell. Whenever I load the view, everything looks fine. However, when I either segue to a new view and then go back to that view from a back button on a navigation controller, or if I scroll up on the table to bring a cell out of the view and go back down the cells view totally screws up and moves the text label to the left and either gets rid of the image or overlays the image on top of the text label. I have seen one similar question on here, but the answers are in objective C or simply do not work. I have tried placing the loading logic in different methods such as viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad, etc. I have tried self.tableView.reload. I have also tried messing with the constraints manually and using tableViews estimatedHeight method. Can anyone help with this? Here is my class:

```
import UIKit
import Parse


var bikeList = [String]()
var customerBikeIDList = [String]()
var customerIndex: Int = 0;

class BikeListController: UITableViewController {

@IBAction func addBike(_ sender: Any) {
   // let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    //let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "addBikeVC")
    //self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addBike", sender: self)
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   //associate user to this device for notification usage
    CommonUtils.addFCMTokenToParse()


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

//was func viewWillAppear
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    let query = PFQuery(className: "Bike")
    if let userID = PFUser.current()?.objectId {
        print("user ID: "+userID)
        query.whereKey("userID", equalTo: userID)
        query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
            if error == nil {
                if let objects = objects {
                    for object in objects {
                        print("printing items from parse query")
                        print(object["userID"])
                        print(object["model"])
                        if(!(bikeList.contains(object["model"] as! String))){
                            bikeList.append(object["model"] as! String)
                            customerBikeIDList.append(object.objectId!)
                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                }
            }else {
                //there was an error
                print("There was an error...")
            }
        })

    }

}

//no reason for having this function here other then idk


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return (bikeList.count)
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! BikeListCell
    cell.theText.text = bikeList[indexPath.row]
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    customerIndex = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "customerViewBike", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "addBike" {
        let navVC = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
        _ = navVC?.viewControllers.first as! AddBikeViewController
    }
}


}
```

Here is the BikeListCell

```
import UIKit

class BikeListCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet var theText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var bikePhoto: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Here is my constraints: 
[image]

Comment: Please, post implementation of BikeListCell.swift, also please post layout constrains of you cell (like an image).

Comment: @Dmitry thanks for the response. I have edited my post for the information you requested. Let me know if you need anything else!